# execute a function when password changed in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

For increase security i'm looking for a way to run a custom function when an *Admin user* change it's password in **Wordpress CMS**.

please help me. thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what kind of __increase security__

Comment: for example I can send sms to user when password changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress sends an email to the admin's email when a user resets their password.

To get a notification when a user changes their password you could hook into the profile_update action which is fired when a user's profile is updated.

When the action is fired WordPress has already validated and updated the user's details we only need to check if the user submitted a password with the request, if it was submitted then the user's password has changed.

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) || '' == $_POST['pass1'] ) {
        return;
    }
    elseif(!$_POST['pass1'] === $_POST['pass2']){
        return;
    }


    // password changed...
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
```

Comment: `profile_update` hook works with all users profile update, If you want to apply function for only admin users then check the capability with `current_user_can()`